# How to encrypt and store data into a database using django and pycrpytodome?

Tags: python, django, pycryptodome

I created a database using django and created a html form to store the data into the database.
Now, I want to encrypt using pycryptodome and store the ciphertext into the database.
And I want the decrypted plaintext when I display the data from the database.

I have tried some basic encryption examples and algorithms from pycrytodome documentation.
Now, I want to encrypt and store the ciphertext into the database.

```py
#This is the function where I want to encrypt the data in the get_password variable and store it
def add(request):
    get_name = request.POST["add_name"]
    get_password = request.POST["add_password"]
    print(type(get_name),type(get_password))
    s = Student(student_name=get_name,student_password=get_password)
    context = { "astudent":s }
    s.save()
    return render(request,"sms_2/add.html",context)
```

```py
#This is the example I have tried from pycryptodome documentation.
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
key=b"Sixteen byte key"
cipher=AES.new(key,AES.MODE_EAX)
data=b"This is a secret@@!!"
nonce = cipher.nonce
ciphertext, tag = cipher.encrypt_and_digest(data)
print(nonce)
print(key)
print(cipher)
print(ciphertext)
print(tag)




cipher1 = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_EAX, nonce=nonce)
plaintext = cipher1.decrypt(ciphertext)
try:
    cipher1.verify(tag)
    print("The message is authentic:", plaintext)
except ValueError:

    print("Key incorrect or message corrupted")
```

I want to encrypt the plaintext I enter into the database using the html form and I want to ciphertext to be stored into the database.
I want help with that.

Comment: Hi. I'm trying to the same thing. Did you ever figure out how to do this?